# WinRT RichEditBox content as HTML text

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, richeditbox

How to get WinRT RichEditBox's content as html string ?

Otherwise I can get the content as RTF string with the following code.

```
  richEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out temp);
```

How to convert this RTF string to HTML string in WinRT application?

Answer (score 0):

you should use some differ way.
 [Here is the link of particular solution](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Html-to-RTF-a757fac5)